# Sending/Receiving Interface

Tags: java, components

I don't know how I would do something like this:
Component A has an input and an output, so does Component B
A's output is connected to the input of B, these connections are one-way (output-> input). an Input can have only 1 connection, however, an output can have as many connections as it likes. If Component B is deleted, the connection between A and B is terminated, same thing if A is deleted. An output sends a single signal to ALL of it's connections. I should also mention that everything runs at a rate of 30 FPS.

My question here is that is how would I go about doing this in java? More importantly rendering it. If there is a library for this, it would be nice to point it out.

(If my question is crap forgive me, it's the second question I've asked on this site)